# Is there a built in way to make custom events in JavaScript natively?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was playing around with JavaScript a little while ago, and it irritated me that I couldn't create my own event.

I've seen Framework's with this built in (jQuery, MooTools, Prototype. Dojo doesn't which is weird because it seems to do everything and your laundry) and I actually built my own system for creating and firing custom events.

It just feels like there should be a native way to do it. Does anyone know how to do this/if you even can?

Comment: Most libraries don't tie into real event systems for custom events. They instead use a simple pub/sub system like [`Backbone.Events`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-9). This may be worth looking at.

Comment: That's how I did mine. I haven't looked into how anyone else does it though.

Comment: **Update:** It's done like this now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dragEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
dragEvent.initEvent("dragged", true, true);
el.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);
```

For official specs, see [DOM Level 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/Overview.html#contents). See also [`createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent), [`initEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent) / [`initMouseEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) / [`initUIEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initUIEvent), and [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) at MDC.

I use this technique to create custom drag and resize events for communication on [this sample page](http://phrogz.net/svg/screen_location_for_element.xhtml).

Comment: So I take it this only works for Elements? Or could you add it to something like an XHR object?

Comment: @tylermwashburn Correct, this is only for DOM Elements.

Comment: **Update:** It's done like this now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events