# pointer-events: none VML raphael solution

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have implemented `pointer-events: none` on a Raphael element using jQuery like this:

```
var raphaelElement = Raphael.ellipse(x,y,w,h);
$(raphaelElement.node).css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
```

This works fine but of course in IE8, Raphael uses VML instead of SVG and this solution fails.

Does anyone have another solution to essentially make a Raphael element ignore events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to make this work for IE8 (and earlier) would be to actually catch the event, and in the event handler:

2. hide the element (`.style.display='none'`)
3. use the [`elementFromPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536417.aspx)  method to find the next element below the 'catcher'
4. [re-create and fire the event on that element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839281/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-make-custom-events-in-javascript-natively) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423800/how-to-invoke-the-mouseenter-event-programmatically-via-jquery))
5. show the catcher again (`.style.display=''`)

This general approach (minus step 3) has been used for over 10 years on IE to allow the user to drag an element with it directly under the cursor while still detecting the 'mouseover' of possible drop target elements underneath.

Comment: nice. very. first time i shared a link which is not my own :)

Comment: I am running in the same problem with Raphael and trying your solution. But in IE8 elementFromPoint returns null instead of the underlying element. Is IE8's elementFromPoint broken? Is there a woraround?

Comment: @Fabian Ask this as its own question along with a sufficiently reproducible test case.