# Setting pointer-events:none with Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using this:

```
circle.attr({
    fill:'#FFFFFF',
    'stroke-width':0,
    opacity:0,
    'pointer-events':'none'
});
```

The problem is mouse events are still caught and in the DOM inspector that property does not show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raphael has a whitelist of attributes it can assign to an element. Since `pointer-events: none` is not supported in VML then this property is not among the whitelist. To work around this you can do...

```
circle.node.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
```

Alternatively, if all circles are non-clickable you can include in your CSS stylesheet:

```
circle {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, none of this will work in any browser that is IE8 or less. If you need old IE support please check out this answer: [pointer-events: none VML raphael solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951868/pointer-events-none-vml-raphael-solution)

Comment: What was the problem with the original code? It should work either way, but the convention in SVG is to avoid using the `style` attribute.

Comment: `pointer-events` is a CSS property, not an attribute. Setting it as an attribute doesn't "hide" it from the mouse.