# Raphael paper catching mouse events in Safari

Tags: safari, raphael

I have a site that uses Raphael to let the user draw arrows on top of the page content while still being able to access the underlying content. To do this, I have a div overlaying the whole page with css set to `pointer-events:none`, and the Raphael paper inside this div. This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari the mouse events are not passing through the overlaid div.

Without the Raphael paper added to the overlaid div the mouse events pass through fine even in Safari. The problem seems to be that the blank Raphael paper is catching the mouse events in Safari. Any idea how to get around this?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T9rD3/.

Comment: there is a workaround, you can do what IE did before pointer-events, it's [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10953755/547020). thanks Phrogz :)

Comment: This error shows up in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows but is fixed in version 6+ (Mac only for now).